# JSF resumable File Upload

Tags: http, jsf, file-upload, resume

I want to upload files with JSF. I want to be able to resume an upload after a pause (voluntarily or not). 
They will be about 500Mb in size.

I'm working with PrimeFaces, which has a neat FileUpload-Tag, but it doesn't let me pause/resume uploads.

I did some research on this. The most common answer is "Use an FTP-Client". Others were Java-Applets or Flash.

It should work on the current Firefox/Chrome and IE8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's indeed not possible to resume file uploads via HTML `<input type="file">` element. There's namely nothing in the `multipart/form-data` encoding which would ever support that. Even more, there's no standard form encoding specification which supports that. You'd basically need to invent a custom HTTP request format.

In Java terms, your best bet is to homebrew an applet or webstart application for this which uses Swing `JFileChooser` to pick files and uses `URLConnection` to send it via HTTP to the server. In the server side, you'd need a custom `Servlet` which understands the custom request format and processes the partial upload accordingly.

There's a 3rd party applet which is capable of this all: [JumpLoader](http://jumploader.com/). Its homepage is at the moment unfortunately down (you could however try Google Cache). To the point, it sends some specific HTTP request parameters along with the `multipart/form-data` upload request telling the server side if it's a partial upload and if so at which index it should start, so that the servlet can glue the pieces together.

Then, to integrate this all with JSF, your best bet is to let the applet pass the session ID around as URL path fragment so that the servlet shares the same HTTP session as the JSF application. This way the upload servlet can access session scoped JSF managed beans and/or the JSF application can poll for some servlet-specific variables in the HTTP session.